# How do I add an external javascript file and run a function via bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Hi I'm trying to make a javascript bookmarklet that will add a link to an external javascript source to a page that is off the domain. However nothing happens when I run the bookmarklet no errors and the code on the page never changes. Any ideas? Here is the bookmarklet I'm trying to use. Thanks for your time.

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://mycode.com/autopopulator.js';autopopulate();})();
```

Comment: You're probably correctly appending the script tag. I suspect the problem is that you have to wait for the browser to load the script before that function call can work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this with a callback:

```
    var addScript=function(filename,callback){
            var e=document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = filename;
            if(callback){
                e.onloadDone=false;//for Opera
                e.onload=function(){e.onloadDone=true;callback();};
                e.onReadystatechange=function(){
                    if(e.readyState==='loaded'&& !e.onloadDone){
                        e.onloadDone=true;callback();
                    }
                }
            }
        if(typeof(e)!=='undefined'){
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);
        }
    }
addScript('http://yoursite.com/js/yourScript.js',function(){functionFromYourScript();});
```

(of course you'll want to optimize this to cram it in a bookmarklet, but you get the idea...)

Comment: heh, turns out I needed it myself, so here's the compressed version (you just need to add your function call with callback to the end of this) javascript:var www=function(f,c){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript";e.src=f;if(typeof(e)!=="undefined"){if(c){e.onloadDone=false;e.onload=function(){e.onloadDone=true;c()};e.onReadystatechange=function(){if(e.readyState==="loaded"&&!e.onloadDone){e.onloadDone=true;c(e.innerHTML)}}}document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e)}};

Answer (score 0):

I've never attempted to create a bookmarklet. But I have found this example online which incorporates jQuery which could be of some use to you.

http://www.latentmotion.com/how-to-create-a-jquery-bookmarklet/

It explains on how to link to external JS files and incorporate other files within that, but I think the kind of thing you are looking for is:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],script=document.createElement('script');script.type='text/javascript';script.src='http://www.site.com/your-javascript.js?' + Math.floor(Math.random()*99999);head.appendChild(script);})(); void 0">Your Bookmarklet Name</a>
```

Comment: That still doesn't show any changes. It is as if it isn't changing anything on the page at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code that

1. inserts the required script tags and then
2. use a timer interval to repeatedly check for an object from the imported script

Here's sample code:

```
function writeTags(){
    //write the script tags
}
function check(){
    // example for prototype library
    if(window.Prototype && Prototype.Version){
        doActualWork();
    }else{
        window.setTimeout(check, 200);
    }
}
function doActualWork(){
    // this your actual code that requires
    // the loaded library
}
writeTags();
check();
```

Comment: I'm curious as to what I accomplish by checking for an object from the script?

Comment: if you find the object, you know the script is loaded and you can use it's methods. it's a common check in JavaScript when working with libraries